# Event queing up on a menu that is supposed to auto hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

My goal is to create a menu that:

1. When you click on the body of the document, the menu pops up
2. when you click on the body again, it hides.
3. when you click on the X, the menu hides.

Below is a function that powers the hiding/showing of this nav. There seems to be event bubbling that gets tied up when you click multiple times on the body. It trips everything up and the events run until the queue is empty.

I'm a bit lost on the best fix.

```
    this.navigationEvents = function () {
        
        // Cache This
        var that = this;

        // On Body Click, Show Nav
        document.body.addEventListener('click', function(){

            // Show Nav Toggle if Anywhere on body is clicked on
            that.navList.parentElement.classList.toggle('show');

            // Set timeout for 30 seconds, toggle menu off after ellapsed time.
            var timeOut = setTimeout(function(){
                // Remove Class: Show
                that.navList.parentElement.classList.remove('show');
            }, that.navViewTime)

        });

        // If 'Controls' is clicked on, stop event from bubbling to body
        this.navList.parentElement.addEventListener('click', function(e){
            // Stop Propagation
            e.stopPropagation();
        });

        // On Nav Item Click, Jump to associated slide index
        $(this.navList).find('li').on('click', function(e){
            // Go To Slide Index
            $(that.target).slick('slickGoTo', $(this).index())
            
            // Hide Menu
            $(document.body).click();

        });

        this.navClose.addEventListener('click', function() {
            $(document.body).click();
        })



    };
```

If you click on the nav element, I have the event stop it's propagation. However, when I click a ton on the body, it goes into this queue of events and the menu hides/shows repeatedly until it's finished.

I can't tell what is going on, I think it may have to do with my `timeOut` also resetting itself. However, when I removed the `setTimeout`, this issue still persisted.

I want to say it's the events queuing up and firing themselves until it's finished (since js is single threaded) but I don't know what the appropriate or best practice would be to fix this issue.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: What if You place `e.stopPropagation()` in first event listener? The body click

Comment: Then the event wouldn't fire, right? Is the stop prog in the wrong place?

Comment: Event will fire, but will not bubble up. Just add second e.stopPropagation() where I told You so. The one, that You have in navList click, leave as is by now.